# How to save countdown timer using SharedPrefences?

Tags: android, save, sharedpreferences, countdowntimer

I have a countdown timer 60 sec. I want the seconds to continue when the user leaves the application. I tried many times but failed.this timer will start counting down when the application is entered.for example, when I enter the application after 20 seconds, the timer will continue in 40 seconds
here my codes

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sp5 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    xtime=System.currentTimeMillis()- 
    sp5.getLong("TIME",System.currentTimeMillis());
    long timer5=mTimeLeftinMilis5-xtime;
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp5.edit();
    editor.putLong("TIME",timer5);
    editor.commit();
}

public void StartTimer5(){
    mCountDownTimer5=new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftinMilis5,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l5) {
            mTimeLeftinMilis5=l5;
            updateCountDownText5();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mTimerRunning5=false;
            btn_kalp5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.kalp);
            cankontrol--;
            tv_countdown5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }.start();
    mTimerRunning5=true;
    xtime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = sp5.edit();
    editor2.putLong("TIME",xtime);
    editor2.commit();
}
```

Comment: You have to clarify your question more.

Comment: According to your question as far as I understood that you want the session that how much user actually used the app?? Is that what you mean?? Correct me If am wrong or clarify the actual requirements.

Comment: I have a 60-second timer.this timer will start counting down when the application is entered.for example, when I enter the application after 20 seconds, the timer will continue in 40 seconds

Comment: @UgurGul by ((entering for second time)), you mean "You will completely close the application?" or you will just pause(get the app to the background) then you will continue?

Comment: i mean completely close and back the menu.I want to give the heart to the user after 60 seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.besli.timer;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CountDownTimer timer;
    int globalTime = 60;
    TextView timeText;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        timeText = findViewById(R.id.timeTextGlobal);
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if(sharedPreferences.getInt("Time",0) != 0){
            globalTime = sharedPreferences.getInt("Time",0);
        }


        timer = new CountDownTimer(globalTime * 1000,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                globalTime -= 1;
                timeText.setText(String.valueOf(globalTime));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                globalTime = 60;
            }
        }.start();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("Time",globalTime).apply();
    }

}
```

This is not a clear solution. But you can check the onStop(). When user tries to exit the app, I get the remaining time and saving it to the cache. Then for the second run, I get that remaining time and start again to countdown.

You can save the current time when the user exits and when user opened your app for the next time, you can calculate the difference. If difference is 300 seconds; you can give 5 more hearts.

For online time you can easily use countdowntimer at the background.

I hope this helps you.